# Should steel siding have a rain screen?

Tags: siding

I am trying to finalize details on a home remodel project that calls for 3" of rigid foam outside the sheathing, then steel board and batten covering the foam. I am trying to figure out the best way to mount the siding since manufacturer suggests it going on horizontal furring. However this does not allow vertical ventilation or drainage unless I do another perpendicular layer of furring. We're talking a pretty thick wall at that point!!

Any suggestions getting vertical board and batten (steel not wood) on an exterior rigid foam house? It is a pretty dry climate in zone 5.

Comment: There is a plastic furring system which might allow vertical drainage. http://www.cor-a-vent.com/sturdi-strips.cfm

Comment: @JimStewart Thanks! This looks like it could work well if it has the strength of 1 x 4's and can be applied horizontally.

Comment: You could also cut slots in wood 1 x 4 s. the slots would be cut 1/8" or 1/4" deep say every 6".  This would be done by racking of a set of 1 x 4 s and cutting a slot through the whole set, then moving over and cutting the next slot, etc. Probably the furring would be attached with the slotted side against the house wrap. Note also there is special rain screen house wrap which is textured and intended to make small gaps between the furring and the housewrap.

Comment: Presumably you intend to attach the insulating foam to the sheathing. This would require special purpose screws (3.5" to 4" long) with special large plastic or sheet metal "washers". Then the furring will be fastened to the sheathing or better yet through the insulation and the sheathing into the studs. Hitting the studs may prove to be difficult: i would think that after the sheathing is up you would have to mark the center of each stud (top and bottom), before of after the sheathing is on, and then when the insulation is on snap a line on the insulation for the center of each stud. ???

Comment: If the plastic furring system were used, the metal siding would have to be fastened with long screws into the sheathing because the plastic furring is only a spacer; it will not hold nails or screws. Whatever system you use, before the sheathing goes on take a photograph and  make a scale drawing showing where the wiring is. With this many fasteners going in you could hit a wire if you don't know exactly where they are.

Comment: How far apart are the fastening points for each piece of steel siding? Are the fastening points on the seams only or does it require fastening in the center of each course of (vertical) siding?